# How to access framset property from frame

Tags: jquery, html

I want to access property of frameset with `id="child_frame"` from frame `name="main"`, so that I can change cols value through jquery

```html
<frameset cols="*" border="0" name="_parent">
    <frameset cols="200,*" border="1" id="child_frame">
        <frameset rows='*' border=0>
            <frame src="localhost/myproject/index.php/menu" name="menu" frameborder="0"/>
        </frameset>
        <frameset rows="*" border="1">
            <frame src="localhost/myproject/index.php/dashboard" name="main" frameborder="1"/>
        </frameset>
    </frameset>
</frameset>
```

Comment: and what did you try? post your code please

Comment: i have tried to get it by using this $('#child_frame').attr('cols'), $(document).parents('frameset').filter('#child_frame'), window.frames.parent but not able to reach frameset with id="child_frame"

Comment: Please edit your post and add the code you tried. That makes it much more readable.

Comment: i am able to get the property through this code but i want to do it with jquery. parent.document.getElementById("child_frame").getAttribute("cols") this code is written in menu frame.